# How do I make a webpage load that little app slide in screen when viewed with an IOS device

Tags: ios, iphone, ios7, popup

you can see what the dialymail.co.uk do in this image.

It looks like it is pulling the information directly from the Apple app store.

I'm looking at the little pop-up / slide in box at the top of my iphone screen which can be closed by the x

So I'm assuming there is some smart apple code I can add.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZefAU.png

after a lot of searching I found the amswer.

Smart App Banners https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/AppleApplications/Reference/SafariWebContent/PromotingAppswithAppBanners/PromotingAppswithAppBanners.html

Answer (score 0):

What you want to do exactly.. i can't understand.Do you need to remove the cross mark at the top left of the screen which is behind the icon image.